# Create a concatenation of values in pandas based on values of another column

Tags: pandas, concatenation

I have 2 dataframes

df1

```
MATERIAL    CODE
paper       a
plastic     b
metal       c
wood        d
glass       e
```

df2

```
NAME    CODE
andy    a,b,d
roger   
danny   c,d
cole    e
```

I want to update df2 with the materials column and concatenate where necessary

Intended result:

```
NAME    CODE    MATERIAL
andy    a,b,d   paper, plastic, wood
roger       
danny   c,d     metal, wood
cole    e       glass
```

Comment: kindly accept the solution if I answered. I noticed you accepted and then unaccepted. Please see: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow on how to accept.

Comment: sorry about that...i was trying to edit the question and i didnt want your right answer to appear in an edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `str.split` to separate the stings into a list in preparation for `explode()`
2. Then, `explode()` and `merge()`
3. Finally, `groupby` and `agg` the columns back to strings with `join`

---

```
df2['CODE'] = df2['CODE'].str.split(',')
df3 = (df2.explode('CODE').merge(df1, how='left',on='CODE').fillna('')
       .groupby('NAME', sort=False, as_index=False)
       .agg({'CODE' : lambda x: ','.join(x), 'MATERIAL' : lambda x: ','.join(x)}))
df3
Out[1]: 
    NAME   CODE            MATERIAL
0   andy  a,b,d  paper,plastic,wood
1  roger                           
2  danny    c,d          metal,wood
3   cole      e               glass
```